# Header with width: 100%; doesn't act as it should

Tags: css, header

Sorry for the title. Wasn't sure what to say really. It's easier to just explain here.

Basically I want a header with relative position that I'm later going to place a navigation menu in. I want it to be 100% wide (so it covers the whole page) and about 130px high. My problem is that there's a little space to the left even when it's set to be 100% wide. So is html/body. On the right side of the header there is no space. I want it to the centered.

Here's my code:

```
html, body {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px; 
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#header {       
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #7a7a7a; 
       -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #7a7a7a; 
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #7a7a7a;
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `margin` of the `body` element to 0.

Answer (score 0):

It happens basically when you do not apply some css rules predefined.Why predefined because some browsers render their own style like margin should be 1px or etc from the body .So you have to  overwrite it with your own css rules .Yes, Levi Botelho gives you the correct answer.Just include the following rules whenever you are going to describe the html content with the help of css.

```
/**
 * 1.0 Reset
 *
 * Modified from Normalize.css to provide cross-browser consistency and a smart
 * default styling of HTML elements.
 *
 * @see http://git.io/normalize
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, audio, canvas, details, figcaption,
figure, footer, header, hgroup, mark, menu, meter, nav,
output, progress, section, summary, time, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

article, aside, dialog, figure, footer, header, 
hgroup, nav, section, blockquote { 
    display: block;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ol {
    list-style: decimal;
}

ul {
    list-style: disc;
}

ul ul {
    list-style: circle;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

ins {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

mark {
    background: none;
}

abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted #000;
    cursor:help;
}

/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;  
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}

input[type="submit"], input[type="button"], button {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

input, select, a img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}



/*
--------------------------------------------------------------------
            End of reset css properties
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
```

Hope the  answer!